# `switch-to-buffer` vs. `pop-to-buffer-same-window`

Tags: buffers, window

What is the difference between `pop-to-buffer-same-window` and `switch-to-buffer`?

`switch-to-buffer-other-window` is basically an alias for `pop-to-buffer`, so I'm surprised that `pop-to-buffer-same-window` is not basically an alias for `switch-to-buffer`.

Comment: Please look at the doc-string for each function at issue and edit your question if you still have any questions regarding the differences between each function.  `M-x describe-function` or `C-h f`.  If you are really curious, then use `M-x find-function` to visit the source-code.  In addition, please look at the doc-strings for the other functions mentioned in the question -- including the one that you *believe* is an *alias*.

Comment: I've looked at the doc-string and source code, thanks. If I'd figured it out from that, I wouldn't have posted the question. And yes, I know `switch-to-buffer-other-window` not a real "alias" for `pop-to-buffer`, just a thin wrapper--that's why I said "basically".

Comment: Please specify just what is unclear to you, after having read the doc, as specifically as possible.

Comment: `switch-to-buffer` opens a buffer in the current window. `pop-to-buffer` opens a buffer in a different window. `switch-to-buffer-other-window` is a thin wrapper around ("alias" for) `pop-to-buffer`. So why isn't `pop-to-buffer-same-window` similarly a thin wrapper around ("alias" for) `switch-to-buffer`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is that `pop-to-buffer-same-window` doesn't insist as much about using the same window.

Historically, `switch-to-buffer` has been used for 2 purposes:

- change which buffer is shown in the selected window.
- display the specified buffer.

In many cases you can do both at the same time, but in some cases you have to choose between the two (e.g. when the selected-window is a minibuffer window).  `switch-to-buffer` cares more about the first, while `pop-to-buffer-same-window` cares more about the second.

Personally I recommend you stay away from `switch-to-buffer` in Elisp code (in 99% of the cases where I see `switch-to-buffer` in Elisp code, the code will misbehave when used with my config).  Better use `pop-to-buffer-same-window` or use `set-window-buffer` depending on your specific needs.

Comment: Great, particularly for the advice about avoiding `switch-to-buffer` in Elisp code and using `pop-to-buffer-same-window`/`set-window-buffer` instead.

Comment: See also https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=28645#25.